# android MaterialBetterSpinner is not getting disable

Tags: android, android-spinner

I tried all that, nothing helped:

```
 spinner.setEnabled(s.getIsEnabled());
 spinner.setClickable(s.getIsEnabled());
 if(!s.getIsEnabled())
 spinner.dismissDropDown();
 for(View lol : spinner.getTouchables() ) {
     lol.setEnabled(s.getIsEnabled());
 }
```

and I can't get :
`getSelectedView()` on that spinner.

can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
spinner.setDropDownHeight(0);
```

works great by now.

Comment: so if I had to enable it again with suppose 3 items on the list, what should be done here ?

Comment: I think this is good option, check out [here](https://gist.github.com/douglasjunior/9d52feb7e0f3158996ec).

Answer (score 1):

```
spinner.setDropDownHeight(0);  // disable
spinner.setDropDownHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // enable
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.